# PHP <li> loop listing the folders in the server

Tags: php, list, loops, smarty

I'm learning PHP "on the go" as I edit a template for a website which I have to do at work, and I'm kinda lost. The original code looks like this:

```
<!-- start of top menubar -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="{$web_var_main_width}" align="center">
<tr style="background-color:#{$web_var_top_tabs_background};">
{php}
    global $lang;
    $this->assign('web_var_top_folder', $this->get_template_vars('web_var_top_folder_'.$lang));
{/php}
<td align="right" style="{if $web_var_top_tabs_image ne "" and $web_var_top_tabs_image ne 0}background:url(http://{$lang}.{$website_name}/{$RSwebPath}utilities/getScaledPicture.php?imageID={$web_var_top_tabs_image}&w={$web_var_top_tabs_image_x}&h={$web_var_top_tabs_image_y}&adj=d) top left repeat-y;{/if}background-color:#{$web_var_top_tabs_background_right};">
{if $folders_structure|@count gt 0}
{if $web_var_top_folder gt 0}
{section name=findtop loop=$folders_structure}
{if $folders_structure[findtop].key eq $web_var_top_folder}{assign var="top_menu" value=$folders_structure[findtop].childs}{/if}
{/section}
{if $top_menu|@count gt 0}
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right">
<tr>
{if $web_var_top_font_size eq "small"}
    {assign var="web_var_top_font_size" value="10px"}
{elseif $web_var_top_font_size eq "medium"}
    {assign var="web_var_top_font_size" value="12px"}
{elseif $web_var_top_font_size eq "large"}
    {assign var="web_var_top_font_size" value="14px"}
{elseif $web_var_top_font_size eq "extra large"}
    {assign var="web_var_top_font_size" value="16px"}
{/if} 
{section name=mytopsec loop=$top_menu}
    <td width="5"></td>
{strip}
{if $top_menu[mytopsec].key eq $folders_selected[1]}
    {assign var="topsel" value="1"}
    <td bgcolor="#{$web_var_top_selected_tabs_color}" style="padding:6px 30px"><span style="font-family:{$web_var_top_font_family}; color:#{$web_var_top_font_color}; font-size:{$web_var_top_font_size}; font-weight:{$web_var_top_font_weight}; font-style:{$web_var_top_font_style}; text-decoration:none">{$top_menu[mytopsec].name}</span></td>
{else}
    <td bgcolor="#{$web_var_top_tabs_color}" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='#{$web_var_top_tabs_hover}'; style.cursor='pointer'; style.cursor='hand'" onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#{$web_var_top_tabs_color}'" style="padding:6px 30px"><a href="index.php?folderID={$top_menu[mytopsec].key}" style=" font-family:{$web_var_top_font_family}; color:#{$web_var_top_font_color}; font-size:{$web_var_top_font_size}; font-weight:{$web_var_top_font_weight}; font-style:{$web_var_top_font_style}; text-decoration:none">{$top_menu[mytopsec].name}</a></td>
{/if}
{/strip}
{/section}
</tr>
</table>
{/if}
{/if}
{/if}
</td>
</tr>
<!-- end of top menubar -->
```

I have to send a folder ID which is the one the code scans into and shows all its childs.

And the function which scans the folders and lists them as menu items is this one:

```
<?
include_once "folderFunctions.php";

global $lang;

$global_deep=0;

$this->assign("folder_structure",getFolderChilds(0,$_SESSION["rs_domain_id"],$lang,"WEB",0,$global_deep));
$this->assign("folder_deep",$global_deep);
?>
```

Which uses the funcion GetFolderChilds from folderFunctions.php:

```
function getFolderChilds($identification,$website,$lang,$type,$local_deep,&$global_deep){
    $child_list=array();

    $childs = @mysql_query("SELECT `HB_IDENTIFICATION`,`HB_TITLE`,`HB_DESCRIPTION`,`HB_IMAGE_IDENTIFICATION`,`HB_LINK` FROM `hb_folders` WHERE `HB_PARENT_IDENTIFICATION` = ".$identification." AND `HB_DELETED`=0 AND `HB_PUBLISHED`=1 AND HB_WEBSITE_ID=".$website.(($type=='image')?(''):(" AND HB_LANGUAGE_ID='".$lang."'"))." AND HB_TYPE='".$type."' ORDER BY HB_ORDER");

    $local_deep++;
    if($local_deep>$global_deep&&@mysql_num_rows($childs)>0) $global_deep=$local_deep;

    while($child = @mysql_fetch_assoc($childs)){
        //$auxPermissions=getPermissions($_SESSION["rs_user_login"],$_SESSION["rs_user_pass"],$website,$child['HB_IDENTIFICATION'],'FOLDER');
        //if($auxPermissions['read']==1){
            $child_list[]=array("key"=>$child['HB_IDENTIFICATION'], "name"=>$child['HB_TITLE'], "desc"=>$child['HB_DESCRIPTION'], "image"=>$child['HB_IMAGE_IDENTIFICATION'], "link"=>$child['HB_LINK'], "childs"=>getFolderChilds($child['HB_IDENTIFICATION'],$website,$lang,$type,$local_deep,$global_deep));
        //}
    }

    return $child_list;
}
```

And its output is something like this (tab changes color when mouse is on it, and so):

[image: Actual code result]

Well, that's what I figured out until now.

The thing is that I want to do a menu with these PHP functions, that is, creating the folders in the server and doing a loop which scans and shows them in my menu.

The thing is, that code uses tables, and has a lot of things which I don't need, such as image tabs and so (I just want to have a text menu with no images).

My question is, how can I implement the function to get the folders and list them not in a table, but in a list, so the output is something similar to this (I want to keep it as simple as posible in order to understand what is being done in any point)?

```
<header>


       <ul class="navigation0">

            <li><a href="#" class="active">start</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>

    </ul> 
</header>
```

Which shows this:

[image: Expected result]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I must use the supplied functions. When I finish this, I will try and update the deprecated functions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've solved it:

```
{php}
    global $lang;
    $this->assign('web_var_top_left_folder', $this->get_template_vars('web_var_top_left_folder_'.$lang));
{/php}

{if $folders_structure_left|@count gt 0}
{if $web_var_top_left_folder gt 0}
{section name=findtopleft loop=$folders_structure_left}
{if $folders_structure_left[findtopleft].key eq $web_var_top_left_folder}{assign var="top_left_menu" value=$folders_structure_left[findtopleft].childs}{/if}
{/section}
{if $top_left_menu|@count gt 0}

{if $web_var_top_font_size eq "small"}
    {assign var="web_var_top_font_size" value="10px"}
{elseif $web_var_top_font_size eq "medium"}
    {assign var="web_var_top_font_size" value="12px"}
{elseif $web_var_top_font_size eq "large"}
    {assign var="web_var_top_font_size" value="14px"}
{elseif $web_var_top_font_size eq "extra large"}
    {assign var="web_var_top_font_size" value="16px"}
{/if} 

<ul class"leftmenu">
{section name=mytopsecleft loop=$top_left_menu}
{strip}
    {if $top_left_menu[mytopsecleft].key eq $folders_selected[1]}
    {assign var="topselleft" value="1"}
    <li><span style="font-family:{$web_var_top_font_family}; color:#{$web_var_top_font_color}; font-size:{$web_var_top_font_size}; font-weight:{$web_var_top_font_weight}; font-style:{$web_var_top_font_style}; text-decoration:none">{$top_left_menu[mytopsecleft].name}</span></li>
{else}
    <li onMouseOver="style.cursor='pointer'; style.cursor='hand'><a href="index.php?folderID={$top_left_menu[mytopsecleft].key}" style=" font-family:{$web_var_top_font_family}; color:#{$web_var_top_font_color}; font-size:{$web_var_top_font_size}; font-weight:{$web_var_top_font_weight}; font-style:{$web_var_top_font_style}; text-decoration:none">{$top_left_menu[mytopsecleft].name}</a></li>
{/if}
{/strip}
{/section}
</ul>

{/if}
{/if}
{/if}
```